# Are $L^p$ spaces hemicompact?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

A topological space $X$ is said to be hemicompact if one can a find a countable family of compact subsets such that every compact subset of $X$ is contained in some set of this family. Is it true that $L^p(\mathbb T^d), p \geq 1$ is hemicompact, where $\mathbb T^d$ is the $d$-dimensional flat torus?

I feel the answer is no but I have no real evidence either way. I am interested in understanding whether $C(X;Y)$ (with the compact-open topology) is metrisable with $X= L^p$ and $Y$ some Polish space. As I understand, a necessary and sufficient condition for this is that $X$ is hemicompact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  A hemicompact space is in particular $\sigma$-compact, since your countable family of compact subsets must cover all of $X$.  But $L^p(\mathbb{T}^d)$ (or more generally, any infinite-dimensional Banach space) is not $\sigma$-compact by the Baire category theorem: any compact subset has empty interior, and thus so does a countable union of compact subsets.